# non standard file "data-raw" note on building/checking a package in R

Tags: r, build, devtools

I get this warning

```
Non-standard file/directory found at top level:
  ‘data-raw’
```

when building my package, even there is the recommendation of creating this folder to create package data http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html#data-sysdata

Any comments on that or do I need a specific setting to get rid of this message.

Comment: Did you also add `data-raw` to `.Rbuildignore`?

Comment: @Gregor ahhh, this was missing... Is this actually stated and I just over read it? Solved the problem... If you like you could post an answer....

Comment: Yes it is, if you search the page you link I'm sure you'll find it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When used, `data-raw` should be added to `.Rbuildignore`. As explained in the [Data section of Hadley's R-Packages book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html#data-sysdata) (also linked in the question)

> Often, the data you include in `data/` is a cleaned up version of raw data you’ve gathered from elsewhere. I highly recommend taking the time to include the code used to do this in the source version of your package. This will make it easy for you to update or reproduce your version of the data. I suggest that you put this code in `data-raw/`. You don’t need it in the bundled version of your package, so also add it to `.Rbuildignore`. Do all this in one step with:
>
> ```
> usethis::use_data_raw()
> ```

Comment: I read this but somehow I didn't linked this to the folder and didn't executed the function... Solved my issue, thanks!

Comment: It would be a good thing for this function to automatically update `.Rbuildignore`.

Comment: @BroVic It does. It will add `^data-raw$` to the end of your `.Rbuildignore` file.

Comment: @GiovanniColitti oh I didn't know that. I will look out for that.